# Prove the generating function for the Bessel function.

Tags: generating-functions, bessel-functions

The generating function states that  $$e^\left (\frac12 \left (t - \frac1t \right ) x\right )= \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} J_n(x) t^n.$$ However, I do not know where the $n = -\infty$ came from in

[image: this image].

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: $w,t,x$ are somewhat missed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical term after the multiplication is:

$$\frac{(-1)^k(\frac{x}{2})^{m+k}}{m!k!}z^{m-k}$$

The author then collects like-terms by 'level' $n=m-k$.